# html5 canvas draw line/s over a css background image

Tags: html, canvas, background-image, draw

I have a html file that has a canvas and sets the background to an 800x800 image. Does anyone know how i can draw lines on top of the image? so even when i zoom in/out the scaling is the same (lines overlaying the image)?

here is my code so far

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Project 1</title>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
canvas { background:url(image.png) }
</style>
</head>
<body> 

<canvas id="canvas" width="800px" height="800px"></canvas>


</body></html>
```

Comment: just standard web browser zooming, or if it went on to a mobile device..the web browser has zoom controls built in. Anyway that is the least of my worries right now

Answer (score 1):

What you draw the last will appear on top.

For your image problem you still can use drawImage() ( in the canvas api )
Example here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial/Using_images

So on each draw() method you call first the draw of your pictures then the draw of your lines.

Personnaly for big project I use a method getzindex() on every object who need to be drawn.
This method return a number, then I sort those numbers and I call the correct draw method of every object in the right order (hope it's understandable)

Comment: dunno about the part in the last paragraph but using drawImage instead of css-background is the right approach as long as the image is served from the exact same domain - else some security exceptions could occure (see "cross origin scripting").